# Accessing minishift from outside

Tags: openshift, gitlab-ci, openshift-origin, minishift

I am testing gitlab integration with minishift and for the same i need the IP that will act as the IP for the external systems. Machine IP is not working.

Is there a way with which I can access minishift from external systems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Minishift runs inside a VM. Go find your VM network settings and let master api port accessible from outside.

Comment: Thanks, I am new to containers can you please elaborate a little.

Comment: [Minishift use different hypervisor, depending on your OS and startup configuration](https://www.openshift.org/minishift/). Find what hypervisor your minishift uses, open that hypervisor's management interface, and search how to configure VM network setting.

Answer (score 1):

> I am testing gitlab integration with minishift and for the same i need the IP that will act as the IP for the external systems

I am not sure what exactly you understand with GitLab integration, but I assume you have some codebase in GitLab and you also have a build config in OpenShift/Minishift. Now you want to trigger a build within Minishift as part of a push to GitLab using a webhook (if these assumptions are not correct, please clarify your question).

Anyways, as pointed out in some of the comments, Minishift is a local development tool. It's network is not intended to be shared to the outside world. In most cases (depdending on the hypervisor your are using), the created network interface is host local only.

Provided you want to test webhooks, I would recommend to try [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) which creates secure tunnels to your localhost. Once you have ngrok installed, you can start a tunnel like this:

```
ngrok tcp `minishift ip`:8443
```

You will get a forwarding TCP connection. Something like `tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:11656`. Now you can use `https://0.tcp.ngrok.io:11656/<remainder of webhook URL>` as the URL to configure in GitLab.

I hope this helps.